# Perl - remove double quotes from file name in a directory

Tags: perl

I'm trying to find the best way to remove double quotes from all files in directory with perl. I know I can do this through 'rename \" "" *'. However when I have that in perl script, perl always complain the double quote is not closed. How can I work around it?

I've tried to call it with backtick inside my perl script `rename \" "" *` but this gave me bash error: 'unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

THe situation I have. I have files in directory with this name 123."ABC".xyz. I want to rename them with perl scripts ideally with rename command.

Thanks,

Comment: It's hard to determine what the bug in your code is without seeing it!

Answer (score 2):

> *How can I work around it?*

No work around is needed; you simply have to fix your bug. To remove remove double-quotes (`"`) from a string, you can use the following:

```
$string =~ s/"//g;
```

---

> *I've tried to call it with backtick inside my perl script `rename \" "" *`*

You did

```
`rename \" "" *`    # Produces the string <<rename " "" *>> and executes it.
```

when you should have used

```
`rename \\" "" *`   # Produces the string <<rename \" "" *>> and executes it.
```